# How to convert solar calendar to lunar calendar in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert solar calendar to lunar calendar in javascript？

I want to use the solar calendar exclusively for the lunar calendar. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## moon-time

moon-time is a component that converts the solar calendar to the lunar calendar (Chinese lunar calendar), it is very simple to use。

#### Install

```js
    npm install moon-time
```

```js
    let moonTimes = moonTime({
        year,
        month,
        day
    })
```

#### npm way

```js
    let moonTime = require('moon-time')
    // import moonTime from 'moon-time'
    
    let moonTimes = moonTime({
        year:2022,
        month:10,
        day:13
    })
    
    console.log(moonTimes);
```

#### javascript way

```js
<body>
    <script src="./calculate"></script>
    <script>
        let moonTimes = moonTime({
            year:2022,
            month:10,
            day:13
        })
        
        console.log(moonTimes);
    </script>
</body>
```